# Cancelling a Delete Query

Tags: sql-server

I executed this query that deletes 16 000 000 rows :

```
delete from [table_name]
```

3 minutes after execution and no results, I cancelled the query.

Took a while to cancel, but in the end it said "Query Cancelled"

Does that mean that any of the 16 000 000 are deleted? Or are they still all there?

*This is not the real query, I just used it for the example.*

Comment: Did you select the data and see? Please have a look [SQL SERVER – ACID](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/09/sql-server-acid-atomicity-consistency-isolation-durability/). This will give you the idea!!

Comment: Was this run in an implicit or explicit transaction? If explicit, did you commit, rollback, or neither?

Comment: Probably still there. The "while" it took to cancel was likely the time spent rolling back. @huMptyduMpty's suggestion should remove all doubt though?

Comment: @Carth this is not the real query, I just used it as an example cause the one Im working on is way more complicated.

Comment: @Carth Not always good advice. You can't use `TRUNCATE` on a table that participates in foreign key relationships. It also doesn't get logged, which *can* be a good thing, but is not always desirable.

Comment: Well assuming your actual `DELETE` was a single statement then either all of the rows will have been deleted or none of them so just do a `SELECT COUNT(*)` matching the `DELETE` and see if the number of rows is approx 16 million.

Comment: @MartinSmith I was asking in general, what applies to all cases. I can't use count(*) in all situations.

Comment: @Carth, you cannot alawys use truncate even to clear out the table. If you have FKs truncate is not allowed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The rows should be there. Delete is rolled back if you cancel the statement.
Once it completes, the changes are committed though.

Answer (score 1):

So, first off - if you want to be sure you can cancel a query successfully, you need to use transactions. IF you were using transactions and that transaction was rolled back, none of the rows would be deleted. Management studio will only use implicit transactions if you have that flag set ([see here](http://blog.techdreams.org/2007/11/implicit-transactions-onoff-sql-server.html)).

That said, I was really intrigued because I figured that a delete operation should be an "atomic" operation so I wrote the following code to test that:

```
create database test_database
use test_database
go

create table sample (
  ID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  value VARCHAR(25)
)

declare @id int 
select @id = 1
-- up 90000 if this doesn't have enough rows
while @id >=1 and @id <= 90000
begin
    insert into sample (value) values ('abcdefg');
    select @id = @id + 1
end

-- run, but cancel in the middle
delete from sample

-- check, are there 90000 records now?
select count(id) from sample

-- clean up
drop table sample
```

Turns out, if you click cancel it does treat this as an "atomic" statement, which means all the rows are still there. Your environment might be different so test it out!